# Retain fragment state on closing app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-tabs

Okay so I have three fragments in a Tab View Activity. I have lists in 2 of the fragments What I want to do is that when I close the app and open some other app and then reopen My app I want to automatically load the last state of the lists in the 2 fragments. Sort of like in the twitter and facebook apps the last synced timelines are already loaded when we open the app. Any idea on how I can achieve this? Just need a sample.

Thanks

Note: These are just normal fragments not listfragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the state of your app to persist across closing the app and reopening it, then you need to save it to a file and reload it when you app starts again. For the type of state you are talking about, SharedPreferences probably makes most sense.

There are different ways to do this, but one way would be to modify your fragment's views as you create them:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate your fragment normally

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
    if (prefs.contains("my_state")) {
        // modify your fragment's starting state with the saved info
    }
}
```

You can save the state of the fragment's views whenever the fragment is paused like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putXyz("my_state", ...);   // put your fragment's state into editor
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that i save my ArrayList in the shared preference and then in the onCreateView function check if shared preference has this ArrayList and if it does i repopulate my adapter and setadapter for my listview again. Did i understand right?

Comment: Well I was more thinking that you could remember where the user was in the list, so you could restore the list position or the current selection. I wouldn't recommend saving your entire list in SharedPrefs -- it works better for a few small items. Without knowing your app's specifics, it's hard to give better advice.